# php date_timestamp_get to seconds

Tags: php

trying to get time in format of seconds in php

```
$date = date_create();
$now= date_timestamp_get($date);
```

output $now = 1454706668
i think this microseconds am not sure (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-timestamp-get.php seem to be missing a bit of info)

i tryd few things non seem to be working right ( google failed me :) )

how do i convert it to seconds?

Comment: That is a unix timestamp, the number of seconds from 1970. Make it the second parameter of http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and you can format it how you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php function

```
time()
```

Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use, `$now = time();` no need to create date.